# C - Last child never reached signal

Tags: c, pipe, fork, ipc, fifo

My code forks n processes. When the last process is reached, it sends a message to the top level process via a FIFO to kill all processes. My code works great, except the the last process never reaches my signal and never gets killed by the top process.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MAX_BUF 1024

int *ptr;
int numprocs;

void signal_handler(int sig){
    int currpid = getpid();
    int lev;
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < numprocs; i++){
        if(ptr[i] == currpid){
            lev = numprocs - i;
            break;
        }
    }

    fprintf(stdout,"EXITING: Level %d process with pid=%d, child of ppid=%d.\n", lev, ptr[i], ptr[i-1]);

    exit(0);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    numprocs = atoi(argv[1]);
    int lev = numprocs;
    bool x = true;

    //create shared memory
    const int SIZE = numprocs * sizeof(int);
    const char *name = "dleggio1OS";
    int shm_fd;
    shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);
    ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    *ptr = getpid();

    //create unnamed pipe
    int pfds[2];
    char buf[30];
    if(pipe(pfds) == -1){
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    //create fifo
    int fd;
    char *myfifo = "/tmp/dleggio1fifo";
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){ //first child ..... keep forking
        //read unnamed pipe
        close(pfds[1]);
        if(read(pfds[0], buf, 3) <= 0){
            perror("child");
            exit(1);
        }
        int check = atoi(buf);
        fprintf(stdout,"ALIVE: Level %d process with pid=%d, child of ppid=%d.\n", check, getpid(), getppid());
        //write to shared memory
        ptr[numprocs - check] = getpid();
        signal(SIGUSR1,signal_handler);
        int i;
        lev--;
        for(i = 2; i < numprocs; i++){
            //create named pipe
            int pfds[2];
            char buf[30];
            if(pipe(pfds) == -1){
                perror("pipe");
                exit(1);
            }

            lev--;
            pid_t pid;

            if((pid = fork()) < 0){

                perror("fork");

                exit(1);
            }

            else if(pid == 0){

                //update shared memory
                ptr[i] = getpid();

                //read from named pipe
                close(pfds[1]);
                if(read(pfds[0], buf, 3) <= 0){
                    perror("child");
                    exit(1);
                }
                int check = atoi(buf);
                fprintf(stdout,"ALIVE: Level %d process with pid=%d, child of ppid=%d.\n", check, getpid(), getppid());
                if(check == 1){

                    //write to fifo
                    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
                    write(fd,"leaf",sizeof("leaf"));
                    close(fd);


                    unlink(myfifo);
                    signal(SIGUSR1,signal_handler);

                }
                signal(SIGUSR1,signal_handler);

            }

            else{
                //write to named pipe
                close(pfds[0]);
                char hold[3];
                sprintf(hold,"%d",lev);
                if(write(pfds[1], hold, 3) <= 0){
                    perror("parent");
                    exit(1);
                }

                wait(NULL);

            }

        }

    }

    else{ //top level
        fprintf(stdout,"ALIVE: Level %d process with pid=%d, child of ppid=%d.\n", lev, getpid(), getppid());
        //write to unnamed pipe
        lev--;
        close(pfds[0]);
        char hold[3];
        sprintf(hold,"%d",lev);
        if(write(pfds[1], hold, 3) <= 0){
            perror("parent");
            exit(1);
        }
        //read from fifo
        char buff[MAX_BUF];
        fd = open(myfifo,O_RDONLY);
        read(fd,buff,MAX_BUF);
        close(fd);
        unlink(myfifo);
        char *comp = "leaf";

        if(strcmp(buff,comp) == 0){
            int j;
            for(j = 0; j < numprocs; j++) printf("%d\n",ptr[j]);
            for(j = 1; j < numprocs; j++) kill(ptr[j],SIGUSR1);
            shm_unlink(name);
            fprintf(stdout,"EXITING: Level %d process with pid=%d, child of ppid=%d.\n", numprocs, getpid(), getppid());
            exit(0);
        }




    }


}
```

Output:

```
./prog1 4
ALIVE: Level 4 process with pid=5129, child of ppid=4692.
ALIVE: Level 3 process with pid=5130, child of ppid=5129.
ALIVE: Level 2 process with pid=5131, child of ppid=5130.
ALIVE: Level 1 process with pid=5132, child of ppid=5131.
5129
5130
5131
5132
EXITING: Level 4 process with pid=5129, child of ppid=4692.
EXITING: Level 3 process with pid=5130, child of ppid=5129.
EXITING: Level 2 process with pid=5131, child of ppid=5130.
```

Comment: what was the status of the child? still running?

Comment: Should `for(j = 1; ...` be `for(j = 0; ...`?

Comment: `fprintf()` is not async-signal-safe, and therefore should not be called by a signal handler.  It's probably moot, since the handler `exit()`s (which also is not async-signal-safe), but you should make it a habit from the beginning to practice async-signal safety.